# Question about error handling in redux toolkit (rejected, fulfilled)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm getting into using redux-toolkit and after reading the docs and implementing some code, there's something I don't quite understand, or maybe my approach is wrong, thats why I'm asking here.

Anyways, I'm having some slice with some asyncThunk which makes a call to an API and sets some state from values returned from that call, and if it fails, show an error notification and some logging. I'm not at work at the moment so I'll write some pseudo code:

```
const loadData = createAsyncThunk('loadData',
    async ({ product }, { dispatch, extra: { API }, rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await API.getProduct(product)
            return response
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(setErrorNotification(error.message))
            dispatch(logError(error))
            rejectWithValue(null)
        }
    }
```

This code does what I want actually, but my question lies in having to use `rejectWithValue(null)`for the code to go through the `rejected` reducer, , which looks really fishy to me and it makes me believe I'm not understanding this quite well. If I don't do this, even if it goes into the catch, it goes through the `fulfilled` reducer which throws an error since this is not expected and there's no payload.

Any pointers? is there a way for, when catching the API call (in case of failure) going to the rejected reducer without having to explicitly `rejectWithValue`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not fishy at all. It is the way to put all burden of changing state to reducers in convenient way. Let's look at code like this: `let promise = promiseReturningFunction();`. Here we have some generic promise and now we can "subscribe" on future value of it with `then` and `catch`. We also can subscribe to future values multiple times, like this:

```js
let promise = promiseReturningFunction();
promise.then(doSomething);
promise.then(doSomethingElse);
```

Redux toolkit preserves this pattern. Thunks are detached from specific slices and you can "subscribe" to them in multiple reducers. So when you want to do multiple things in different slices on same result, you will get *raw* data from thunk and in different slices process that data as you need in particular case.

In your case, you should call `return rejectWithValue(error)`. Then, in slice that is responsible for errors you add this:

```js
extraReducers: {
  [loadData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
    // do something with error that is in action.payload
  }
}
```

This is good pattern in case when you handle errors in one slice, but might need to know that it settled in another. It is also future proof in two ways: you always can add slice that use same thunk, and you always can replace thunk completely without breaking things (if shapes of data don't change).

### Update

Example sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cdn-d86c9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Appreciate the response. What I'm not quite getting in your suggestion is that, since I'm handling the errors in another slice, I can't do much inside the rejected reducer, since I only have access to that current slice. Thats why I have the `setErrorNotification(error.message)`, so I can set the error notification in the 'errors' slice.
I guess I could make a selector to get errors from individual slices and set the notification from that selector, that way, the rejected reducer would actually set state and make sense.

Comment: I've added live example on how you can access results of the thunk in different slices

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog thank you for this - really helped! The key learning for me is that I can trigger a extraReducer in multiple slices from a asyncThunk